# SQL query date null check

Tags: sql

I have the following stored procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spList_Report] 
  @id INT, 
  @startDate DATETIME = NULL, 
  @endDate DATETIME = NULL, 
  @includeStatus1 BIT, 
  @includeStatus2 BIT, 
  @includeStatus3 BIT, 
  @includeStatus4 BIT 
 
AS 
  SET NOCOUNT ON 
 
  SELECT * 
  FROM 
    tblProducts as products 
  WHERE  
    product.intID = @id 
    AND product.dateMain >= @startDate  
    AND product.dateMain <= @endDate
```

If `@startDate` AND `@endDate` are both `null` then I want it to return the rows ignoring the date check in the where clause.

How?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do

```
AND product.dateMain >= ISNULL( @startDate, 0)
AND product.dateMain <= ISNULL( @endDate, product.dateMain + 1)
```

`ISNULL` yields the second value, if the first value is null.

Thus:

if `@startDate` is null, then `dateMain` must be bigger than 0 (1900-01-01)

if `@endDate` is null, then `dateMain` must be smaller than `dateMain + 1 day`

Answer (score 2):

you can try something like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spList_Report] 
  @id INT, 
  @startDate DATETIME = NULL, 
  @endDate DATETIME = NULL, 
  @includeStatus1 BIT, 
  @includeStatus2 BIT, 
  @includeStatus3 BIT, 
  @includeStatus4 BIT 

AS 
  SET NOCOUNT ON 

  SELECT * 
  FROM 
    tblProducts as products 
  WHERE  
    product.intID = @id 
    AND product.dateMain >= ISNULL( @startDate, product.dateMain )  
    AND product.dateMain <= ISNULL( @endDate,  product.dateMain )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize an "or" in your Sql, but since this is a stored procedure:

```
If @startdate is null Or @enddate is null
   begin
      select without using a date range
   end
Else
   begin
      select using date range
   end
```

Comment: that's a lot of duplication, though, for something for which there are simpler solutions (Lieven, IordanTanev and me all getting at the same solution)

Answer (score 0):

I would use Kris Krause's solution, but change the "IF" statement to use "AND".  I think if you use the first two solutions the query engine may perform a table/index scan on the date fields.  You want to keep your queries as concise as possible for best performance, so don’t run queries on unnecessary columns.

```
IF @startdate IS NULL AND @enddate IS NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM tblProducts as products WHERE  
    product.intID = @id 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM tblProducts as products WHERE  
    product.intID = @id 
    AND product.dateMain >= @startDate  
    AND product.dateMain <= @endDate 
END
```